# Is it possible for data to change after updating mysql version on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

I updated mysql through apt-get. shortly after i noticed some data in a column was changed. this columns data type is int(3) but the data was something like 403929319494. Is it possible? or was i hacked?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a hack.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html
*The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.*

Comment: yes, but is it a possible update problem? how else can something like this happen? i know for a fact i didn't set the data to this value.